# Performance issue for parallel execution for 10 or more query in Cloudera

Tags: hive, cloudera

I am performing a parallel execution of 10 or more select query on different column of a same table throw my application then its taking 2 to 3 minute for one query.
If my query count is less than or equal to 5 then its taking 24 second for per query for parallel execution. I am using Cloudera-5.14.2. and Hive database. I tried below solution but not able to improve performance .

1- TEZ:

```
set hive.execution.engine=tez;
```

2- VECTORIZATION:

```
set hive.vectorized.execution.enabled = true;
set hive.vectorized.execution.reduce.enabled = true;
```

3- COST BASED QUERY OPTIMIZATION:

```
set hive.cbo.enable=true;
set hive.compute.query.using.stats=true;
set hive.stats.fetch.column.stats=true;
set hive.stats.fetch.partition.stats=true;
set hive.stats.autogather=true;
```

Is there any way i can improve the performance for parallel execution in hive.
what is parallel execution flow for hive.

Comment: Can u please provide some details about your cluster size, what type of vm and its resources.

Comment: Hardware - 
4 nodes : 2 VM are on 1 hypervisor and 2 VMs are on another hypervisor.  Both hypervisors are in the same rack connected to the same in rack switch ( 1GB)